# VBA On Error AddSheet

Tags: vba, excel

so I am trying to use On Error to accomplish the following. I am trying to select the next sheet from the active sheet (trying to avoid using sheet names). If this generates an error, i.e. there is no sheet after the active sheet, then a new sheet needs to be added. I was hoping there was something as simple as If... Is Error Then ...., but there isn't.

I have tried multiple variations of On Error with no luck. Even in cases where there is another sheet after the active one, thus no error, it still creates a new sheet, but I just want it to select that sheet. It should only add a sheet when it goes to select the next sheet and an error is generated. Any suggestions?

```
On Error GoTo AddSheet:
Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
AddSheet:
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Resume Next
```

Just tried this one too with no luck:

```
On Error GoTo AddSheet:
Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
Resume Label1:
AddSheet:
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Label1:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is `Resume Label1:`

Change this to `Goto Label1:`

**Addendum**: I didn't know why Goto should be used instead of Resume so I did some experimentation.

In the following code Resume effectively ignores the provided tag because Resume is designed to go inside Error Handlers. Since no error has occurred instead any call to Resume pushes the code to the Label defined in `On Error GoTo <Label>` even if you just call `Resume` with no Label.

```
Sub ErrorHandlingPlay()
    On Error GoTo AddSheet
    Resume Label1: 'Resume moves flow to AddSheet instead
Label1:
    Exit Sub
AddSheet:
    Debug.Print "This gets printed."
End Sub
```

But if you put Resume inside your error handling label, it successfully moves flow:

```
Sub ErrorHandlingPlay()
    On Error GoTo AddSheet:
    Debug.Print 1 / 0 'To throw an error
Label1:
    Exit Sub
AddSheet:
    Resume Label1: 'Flow successfully moves to Label1 after the error is caught.
    Debug.Print "This is not printed"
End Sub
```

So essentially... Use `Resume` if you are using it from within your Error Handling Label. Otherwise use `Goto`.

Comment: This causes any code following the second `Label1` to be executed while still in an "error handling block". Insert a `Resume Label1` directly before `Label1:` to exit the Error Handler. Quoting the link in my answer: "Resume is the only way, aside from exiting the procedure, to get out of an error handling block." I prefer the method that my answer provides because It only requires one jump and all error handling will be found at the end of the procedure.

Comment: @Zak In the OPs code, his attempt to call Resume was "sort of" not in the error handling block yet. Honestly, if I was trying to give him the best solution, I would recommend just making a custom SelectNext sub which handles all of his code, but I was just telling him how to make his current code work as he wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tell you program to leave the subroutine before if gets to line in question. You also want `Resume` instead of `Resume Next` to retry the line that cause the error, which in this case I think that you would.

```
On Error GoTo AddSheet:
Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
Exit Sub 'or Exit Function if you are in a function
AddSheet:
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Resume
```

And note that when actually applying this:

```
Sub Foo()

' Some Code

On Error GoTo AddSheet:
Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
On Error GoTo 0 'This turns off the error handling in case after it is no longer needed

' the rest of your code

Exit Sub
AddSheet:
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Resume
End Sub
```

More info: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: This is good, but I'd like it more if you removed the rest of your code to a different method, which calls this one.